# source.data is updated in bokeh serve but plot does not change

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to make a bokeh serve plot with a CheckButtonGroup. I manage to update my source.data but the plot does not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

In reality, I import the dataset from my computer, but for now I will create an example pandas dataframe. I want to select the 'x' column (as x-axis variable) and one or more of the other columns (as y-axis variables).

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y1','y2','y3'])
dataset['x'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dataset['y1'] = [10, 20, 30, 40]
dataset['y2'] = [11, 21, 31, 41]
dataset['y3'] = [12, 22, 32, 43]

pos_cols = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'] # possible column names
col_list = ['y1', 'y2'] # default columns in plotted data
use_data = dataset[col_list]
use_data['x'] = dataset.loc[:, 'x']

source = ColumnDataSource(use_data)

p = figure(
   tools="pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,reset,save",
   x_axis_label='xtitle', y_axis_label='ytitle',
   title="Simulations"
)

# make default plot with the two columns
for column in col_list:
    p.line('x', column, source=source)

check = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=["y1", "y2", "y3"], active=[0, 1]) # A check box for every column

def update_lines(new):

    col_list = [pos_cols[i] for i in new]
    use_data = dataset[col_list]
    use_data['x'] = dataset.loc[:, 'x']
    source.data = source.from_df(use_data)

    print(source.data) # source.data is correctly updated, but does not seem to trigger a new plot

check.on_click(update_lines)

doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(row(check, p, width=800))
doc.title = "Simulations"
```

I save the code as try.py and run it from the windows prompt with bokeh serve try.py. The plot is visible at http://localhost:5006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating glyphs for columns like `'y3'` up front, but not actually sending any column `'y3'` to start. Bokeh does not like that (you can see error messages about trying to access non-existent columns in the browser JS console)

A better approach, that also does not unnecessarily re-send all the data, might be to just toggle the `.visible` attribute of the glyph renderers. Here is a minimal example (that starts with all lines visible, but you could change that):

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import CheckboxButtonGroup, ColumnDataSource

dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y1','y2','y3'])
dataset['x'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dataset['y1'] = [10, 20, 30, 40]
dataset['y2'] = [11, 21, 31, 41]
dataset['y3'] = [12, 22, 32, 43]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dataset)

p = figure( )

lines = []
for column in ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']:
    lines.append(p.line('x', column, source=source))

check = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=["y1", "y2", "y3"], active=[0, 1, 2])

def update_lines(new):
    for i in [0, 1, 2]:
        if i in new:
            lines[i].visible = True
        else:
            lines[i].visible = False

check.on_click(update_lines)

doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(row(check, p, width=800))
```

Alternatively, if you are just looking to be able to hide or mute lines, an much easier way would be to use Bokeh's built in Interactive Legends:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html#userguide-interaction-legends

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot. This seems a nice solution. However, what to do if I want the user of the plot to specify which slice of the data to plot. For instance when I have four columns and I want them to specify which should be the x-axis variable and which the y-axis variable. Then I would need to be able to update the plot (by updating the data) without having all the data in the start plot. I am wondering how I can make the source.data update to actually do its work in the plot?

Comment: One option would be to simply create a new figure. See e.g. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter/main.py Alternatively, you can change the actual data in a data sources. There's other ways too I'm sure. The only thing to keep in mind is that if you glyph that says "display column 'foo'" then column "foo" needs to exist. That was your problem above.